# R: plm -- year fixed effects -- year and quarter data

Tags: r, regression, linear-regression, plm

I am having a problem setting up a panel data model.

Here is some sample data:

```
library(plm)

id <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2)
year <- c(1999,1999,1999,1999,2000,2000,2000,2000,1999,1999,1999,1999,2000,2000,2000,2000)
qtr <- c(1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4)
y <- rnorm(16, mean=0, sd=1)
x <- rnorm(16, mean=0, sd=1)

data <- data.frame(id=id,year=year,qtr=qtr,y_q=paste(year,qtr,sep="_"),y=y,x=x)
```

I run the following regression using 'id' as the individual index and 'year' as the time index:

```
reg1 <- plm(y ~ x, data=data,index=c("id", "year"), model="within",effect="time")
```

Unfortunately, I get the following error:

> duplicate couples (time-id)   Error in pdim.default(index[[1]], index[[2]]) :

So to get around that, I use the combined variable that is 'y_q':

```
reg1 <- plm(y ~ x, data=data,index=c("id", "y_q"), model="within",effect="time")
```

But here's my issue -- I only want to have year fixed effects and not year-quarter.

Is there another way to get around the earlier issue instead of making the tiem index 'y_q'?

Thanks ahead of time for any help!

Comment: see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28789767/how-to-include-a-year-fixed-effect-in-a-year-quarter-panel-data-in-r-using-plm

Answer (score 3):

In a panel setting, you usually don't have some duplicate value for each couple id-year.

In your quaterly data it will be difficult to compute a year fixed effect models without aggregating your data to make them yearly.

Check the examples [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Panel_data) to see how your data should be formatted for panel data modeling.

Here is oneway to do that :

```
require(plyr)
yeardata  <- ddply(data, .(year, id), summarize, y = mean(y),
                                                 x = mean(x))


require(plm)
reg1 <- plm(y ~ x, data = yeardata, index = c("id", "year"), model = "within", effect = "time")
fixef(reg1)

##      1999      2000 
## 0.2641997 0.0041193
```